# Get MR related data from Gitlab API

Tags: api, gitlab, git-commit, gitlab-api

How to:

1. Get all commits in a **particular** Merge Request.
2. Get all users who committed in a **particular** Merge Request.
3. No. of lines added/deleted/updated by a **particular** *user* in a Merge Request.

Can't find how to use Gitlab API(http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/) for getting all the above mentioned. Is there a way Gitlab API can help to get these directly or by introducing some sort of hack.

Answer (score 1):

For the first point, I think you are looking for this:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ****" "http://gitlab/api/v3/projects/:project_id:/merge_requests/:mr_id:/commits"
```

the Second point can be found with the attribute author of

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ****" "http://gitlab/api/v3/projects/:project_id:/merge_requests/:mr_id:
```

the last point is trickier, when you have the list of commit, you can get the diff

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ****" "http://gitlab/api/v3/projects/:project_id:/repository/commits/:sha/diff
```